# How to reduce margin between a fixed navbar and div below it?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have got a fixed navbar at the top of viewport, just below it there is a div containing an image file. It works nicely for large devices, but **when the viewport becomes smaller, there comes a gap between navbar and image file**. I am out of clue to solve these.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link type="text/css"  href="tex.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/profile.jpg"></div>
        </div> 


        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="margin-bottom:0px;">

            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
              </button>

            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
              </ul>

            </div>

        </nav>

    </nav>

</div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/imgg.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body{
padding-top:150px;
}
```

Comment: This cannot possibly be all relevant CSS, no?

Comment: Aren't answering you answering your own question now? It probably has something to do with the body padding. Media queries should help you with this.

Comment: Demo it or it didn't happen. Try [**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/new)

Comment: I don't know how to solve the issue. till this point i used this much of css only.